# Using getchar() after read()

Tags: c, unix, console, stdout, stdin

c for keyboard capture. Following code finds when an arrow key/ esc is pressed. At the same time I want to read whole words that user inputs and these should be shown on **stdout** as well.

```
char pp = 0;
char p = 0;
while( (i = read(0, &c, 1)) == 1) {
if (pp == 033 && p == 0133 && (c &= 255) == 0102) /* DOWN */ break;
if (c == 0177) /* ASCII DELETE */ break;
printf( "%o, %o, %o\t%s\n\r", pp, p, c, &c);
pp = p;
p = c; 
}
...
...
getchar(); //I want to capture here what was entered before
           //  **return key** was pressed.
```

But this code does not work if I remove '\n'. 
I want stdout should behave as a normal shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf(3)` goes through the `<stdio.h>` buffered I/O facility, which includes `fputs(3)` and `fputc(3)`. You are observing the normal line buffering behavior. You can defeat this buffering as noted with `setbuf(3)`, however, since you don't want it in the first place and you are already using a direct kernel call (`read(2)`) for reading, why not change your logic just a little to directly call the kernel with `write(2)` as well?

```
char buffer[100];

int n;

n = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "format string...", args...);
write(1, buffer, n)
```

And if you wanted to, you could define your own directPrintf to make this easier:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int directPrintf(const char *format, ...)
{
va_list ap;
char buffer[200];

    va_start(ap, format);
    int n = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return write(1, buffer, n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` is likely implemented in terms of a `read()` that reads far more than 1 byte (usually a whole `PIPE_BUF`, or 4096 bytes). It then maintains a private cursor to that buffer, extracting bytes as needed.

This is done because `read()` has a non-trivial overhead associated with just *calling* it.

`printf()`, and `fwrite()` (and etc) also buffer for the same reason (`write()` has a non-trivial overhead). The call to `fflush(stdout)` will translate into a `write()` call of whatever has been buffered, but not sent to the underlying IO port.

Finally, you have `\n\r` backwards; it's almost certainly supposed to be `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

insert

```
setbuf( stdout, NULL);
```

somewhere at the start and remove the \n.